# jQuery Ajax Combo box not working

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have the following combo box which sets the number of images displayed per page. I had the original php code working, but I am having a lot of trouble using jQuery to change it to Ajax.

It appears the combo box part is working, but it's hard to tell as the images are not displaying.
I'm hoping someone can help me.

**The HTML**

```
<form>
    <label>Images Number:</label>
    <select id="imgNum" name="imgNum">
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>      
    </select>
</form>

<div id="imgTray"></div>
```

**The jQuery**

```
//Bind the onChange event to Fetch images on combox selection
$("#imgNum").change(function(){
    //The combo box
    var sel = $(this);
    //Selected value
    var value = sel.value();

    //Fetch the images
    $.get("get_images.php",{imgs: value}, function(data){
        //Add images to the document
        $("#imgTray").html(data);
    });
})

//You should store the current selected option in a cookie
//For the sake of the example i'll set the default permanently to 12
var imgNum_selected = 12;

//set the initial selected option and trigger the event
$("#imgNum [value='"+imgNum_selected+"']")
    .prop("selected","selected")
    .change();
```

**The PHP**

```
<?php

    if((int) $_GET['imgs'] > 0){ 
        $limit = (int) $_GET['imgs']; 
    } else { 
        $limit = 12; 
    }

     $curPage = 0;
     if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $curPage = (int) $_GET['page'];
     }

    $mysql_link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");   
    mysql_select_db("new_arrivals_imgs") or die("Could not select database");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `imgURL`,`imgTitle` FROM `images` ".
    "ORDER BY `imgDate` DESC LIMIT " . $limit * $curPage . ", $limit") or die(mysql_error());

    if(!$query) {
        echo "Cannot retrieve information from database.";
    } else { 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
        echo "<li><a href='new_arrivals_img/".$row['imgURL']."' class='gallery' title='".$row['imgTitle']."'><img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/".$row['imgURL']."'></a></li>";
      }
    }

?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, the method is [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val), not `value()`:

```
var value = sel.val();
```

For example (without the AJAX stuff): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/u3c9G/

Comment: Genius! I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you very much.

Comment: Quick question. I have a separate Ajax document for pagination. It's working perfectly, however I would like to integrate this feature with the pagination feature. Would this entail a complete re-write? Or is it possible to just place this code with the other code? Would I need to have the php in separate files? I wonder about that since they would need to share common information such as current page and images per page.

Comment: @stefmikhail: I'd have to say "maybe". Hard to say without more details.

Comment: Would you be willing to take a look at it for me? I'm starting to realize I need to perhaps take a course, or find someone that can explain how Ajax works with jQuery, and how to use it. I get everything else by its self, but it's putting it all together that's the problem. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @stefmikhail: I see you went the "ask another question" route, cool.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'm now trying to combine this code with another Ajax code, but with no luck. Any chance you could help me out with it? I need to understand what's going wrong so I can start figuring these things out for myself. If you could I would be extraordinarily grateful. Thanks.